# Acceptability of questions about checking for race conditions

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it acceptable for users to post questions in this community and have their code evaluated by others to check for race conditions? Or do these types of questions fall under the banner of 'broken code' and therefore violate the rules for posting questions?

Code posted that contains race conditions *may* always resolve correctly, but because there exists the possibility that they could incorrectly evaluate, should they be considered valid for this community?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you *know* that your code has a race condition then it is broken. Take it home and fix it then bring it back. If it *might* have a race condition but you just aren't certain then it certainly falls into the scope of what is reviewable. Like many review requests it comes of as "I'm just not certain if I did this correctly. Can I have another set of eyes, please?" Just bear in mind if ***all*** you want from your review is to verify that there are no race conditions then it doesn't fall under the "any and all aspects of the code" umbrella.